# How to copy/clone RSNNS network in R?

Tags: r, neural-network

I would like to create multiple copies of my network instance to predict mutliple independent waves. Unfortunately simple reassigning does not work in this case, so what can I do?

I attached a reproducible demo that shows that the results of predictions of both copies should be exactly the same, but they are not:

```
library(RSNNS)
points = sin(seq(1,20,0.1))
input = head(points,-1)
output = tail(points,-1)
net = elman(input, output, maxit=1000)
netCopy1 = net
netCopy2 = net
print(predict(netCopy1, as.matrix(input[1:10])))
print(predict(netCopy2, as.matrix(input[1:10])))
```

Answer (score 0):

the RSNNS models are C++ objects, this is why copying just the R pointer doesn't work. To deep-copy such a model, RSNNS has an object serialization mechanism. The easiest way to use it is to save your model to disk and load it, e.g. as follows:

```
library(RSNNS)

set.seed(10)

points = sin(seq(1,20,0.1))
input = head(points,-1)
output = tail(points,-1)
net = elman(input, output, maxit=1000)
netCopy1 = net

saveRDS(net, file="./net.RData")
netCopy2 = readRDS("./net.RData")

print(predict(netCopy1, as.matrix(input[1:10])))
print(predict(netCopy2, as.matrix(input[1:10])))
```